# Signal handler function call ambiguity

Tags: c, signals, atoi

While I was solving one of the problems in a wargame, I encountered a strange behaviour of signal function in C. As far as my understanding goes,

```
void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int)
```

sig is the signal number here on encountering which the handler function func is called.
The code which in which I was trying to find the exploit was this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void catcher(int a)
{
    setresuid(geteuid(),geteuid(),geteuid());
    printf("WIN!\n");
    system("/bin/sh");
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 3 || !atoi(argv[2]))
            return 1;
    signal(SIGFPE, catcher);
    return abs(atoi(argv[1])) / atoi(argv[2]);
}
```

What my task is to execute the shell which is being executed from the catcher function, which means if anyhow I am able to guide my control flow to run the catcher function - I am done. One method which I found out for this was to use the fact that atoi function accepts integers less the minimum 32 bit signed interger i.e.`-2,147,483,647`, so what we can do is to provide the first argument as `-2,147,483,649` and second argument as `-1` which finally will lead to the value `2,147,483,649` being passed to atoi and will result in SIGFPE. This approach works fine practically too.
What my doubt here is that even if we use the above approach, the return statement is executed after the signal() function is used. How is it then that the program is running backwards by one instruction and launching the catcher() handler function when there is SIGFPE in the usage of atoi?

Comment: Posix states that continuing after a `SIGFPE` is Undefined Behaviour. Also, `printf` and `system` are not async safe functions and must not be called in a signal handler.

Comment: `signal` just sets the function to be called later when the signal happens. It basically does `sigfpe_handler = &catcher;` (where `sigfpe_handler` is actually some variable you can't access directly)

Comment: @immibis so does that mean that on encountering signal() function, the program launches another thread which then waits for the specified interrupt to occur?

Comment: I think you mean to use -2147483648 and -1 to trigger the signal.

Comment: @ShivanshRai *so does that mean that on encountering signal() function, the program launches another thread which then waits for the specified interrupt to occur?*  No.  `signal()` installs a function that will be called when the specified signal is sent to the program.  When that signal is raised a current thread is interrupted and the signal handler that was installed with the call to `signal()` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is it then that the program is running backwards by one instruction and launching the catcher() handler function when there is SIGFPE in the usage of atoi?

It doesn't. `signal(SIGFPE, catcher);` tells the Linux kernel, "Hey, if I ever get a `SIGFPE`, call `catcher`, okay?"

Then when your program gets a `SIGFPE`, just like you asked, the kernel makes sure `catcher` gets called - instead of killing your program, which is what it would normally do if you hadn't asked it to call `catcher`.

Comment: I get it now, thanks. Is the scenario same in the case of try-catch blocks? Even there we specify the particular exceptions which when encountered, perform the specified instructions instead of killing the program.

Comment: @ShivanshRai They're completely different, but the same overall idea yes.